# I am trying to download pdf file but i am getting error using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to download PDF file on button click but unfortunately i am getting error please help me how can i solve this issue ? thanks

**getting error**

https://flareapp.io/share/NPLYOq27

**controller**

```
public function fileDownload(Request $request,$id){

        $book_cover = BookLibrary::where('id', $id)->first();

        $path = config('markaz.file_url') . $book_cover->file;

        return response()->download($path, $book_cover->original_filename, ['Content-Type' => $book_cover->mime]);

}
```

**html view**

```
 <div class="download-read">
                      <a  href="{{route('book.file.download',$book->id)}}">Download <i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>
                    </div>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/books/file/download/{id}', [LiteratureController::class, 'fileDownload'])->name('book.file.download');
```

Comment: the file doesn't exist, seems very straightforward to me

Comment: check file is stored in `storage` or `public` dir ?

Comment: File is storing in public/uploads/markaz

Comment: why are you using a URL not a file path?

Comment: How can I make correct file path ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$book_cover->file` is path to your file ?
From error message, it look like just file name.
Please re-check it!
If `$book_cover->file` is only file name, so you should get file path and put it into download().

```
$filePath = public_path()."/downloads/info.pdf";
return response()->download($filePath);
```

Comment: this is a answer column, you need to write answers here not ask questions

Comment: @bhucho Thank for your comment. But I think sometime a question can become an answer.